# Flutter using hyphenation with \u00ad in a Text widget and only if applied then replace with a soft hyphen (-)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there is a way to do hyphenation with \u00ad in a Text widget and only if the hyphenation is applied then it should replace a soft hyphen symbol (-) on the word break?

for example:

```
Hyphen\u00adation text
```

should look like if text is not breaking

```
Hyphenation text
```

or like this if the text is splitted up in two lines with a (-) symbol

```
Hyphen-
ation text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote this StatelessWidget for that purpose:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextWithHyphenation extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWithHyphenation(
    this.data, {
    Key? key,
    this.style,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String data;
  final TextStyle? style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
      final String text = data;
      final span = TextSpan(text: text, style: style);
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: span, maxLines: 2, textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr)
        ..layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);

      final TextSelection selection =
          TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: text.length);
      final List<TextBox> boxes = textPainter.getBoxesForSelection(selection);
      final int lines = boxes.length;
      if (lines > 1) {
        // The text has more than a line
        return Text(text.replaceFirst('\u00ad', '\u00ad-'), style: style);
      } else {
        return Text(text, style: style);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note, that this only works for one `\u00ad` char inside a String resource.

Comment: this solution is not working if the the text is not breaking but with the lines condition it still inserts the - e.g.: "Hypthen\u00adation Longtext"  is looking like this: "Hyphen-ation Longtext" maybe the condition should check if the first word fits in the first line

Comment: @th_lo Sorry, exactly that is working inside my app. Working both with one line and with two lines if not enough space. Just tested it again.

Comment: sorry. I have to clarify what I mean. your solution works but only in the case I've written. There are two problems: 1st case: you have two Words. Both words are with "\u00ad", e.g. "Hypthen\u00adation Long\u00adtext". the second hyphenation isn't replaced. 2nd case: you have two words with one hyphenation e.g. "Hypthen\u00adation Longtext". this rendered as two lines, first line: "Hypthen\u00adation", second line: "Longtext", but each word one line. In this case your widget is replacing the "\u00ad" with "\u00ad-" so it looks like first line: "Hypthen-ation" and second line: "Longtext".